# Are event listeners from an EventSource automatically garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, server-sent-events

I've seen answers on Stackoverflow mentioning how if a DOM element goes out of scope, its event listeners are automatically garbage collected. Is that *also* the case with non-DOM elements, such as [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource)?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
function checkStatus(events) {
   return function() {
     if (events.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED) { 
       establishSSE(); // Is this fine?
     } else {
       setTimeout(checkStatus(events), 500);
     }
   }
}

function establishSSE() {
  const events = new EventSource("/sse/" + sseID);

  events.addEventListener("reply", sseReply);
  events.addEventListener("refresh", sseRefresh);

  setTimeout(checkStatus(events), 500);
}

establishSSE();
```

(I know I can use the `onerror` event. This is just an example)

In this case, would the previous event handlers be garbage collected when `establishSSE` was re-ran on line 4?

---

**Edit:**

I don't understand how these values can be garbage collected. For example, the following works:

```
function sseSubscribe() {
  let events = new EventSource("/v1/sse/mySSEID");

  events.addEventListener("message", sseHeartbeat);
  events.addEventListener("reply", sseReply);
}
```

That is, new messages still cause the `message` and `reply` handlers to run.

But `events` is no longer accessible from anywhere within the program. So, shouldn't it have been garbage collected? It seems like `EventSource` is never garbage collected (unless maybe the connection is broken?)

---

**Edit #2:**

It seems that *even* if the event handlers are anonymous, like so:

```
function sseSubscribe() {
  let events = new EventSource("/v1/sse/SSEID");

  events.addEventListener("message", function() {
    console.log("Heartbeat");
  });
 }

 sseSubscribe();
```

This *still* works on my end. That is, `Heartbeat` is being logged into the console every 30 seconds (the interval my server sends them). This is despite `events` immediately going out of scope and being inaccessible anywhere else in the program.

Comment: Yes, an event source won't be garbage collected until it is closed - until then, it may receive events from the network and is kept alive for that.

Comment: @Bergi Are you sure closing the event handler actually allows it to be garbage collected? I'm reading the Chrome source code at the moment and (unless I am missing something) it doesn't seem like calling `close` on the `EventSource` would flag the object for being available for garbage collection. https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/modules/eventsource/event_source.cc;l=209;bpv=0;bpt=0

Comment: I don't know how GC works in Chrome at the C++ level, but I would expect the stopped timer and the cancelled loader to be freed and remove the reference to the event source from the global root.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#garbage-collection

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to question title**

Yes and no (from comment). The event source *value* can be garbage collected when it can't be accessed anywhere<sup>1</sup>. When and if it is garbage collected, any *anonymous* event handler functions declared as inline arguments to `addEventListener` will be garbage collected. Functions defined more globally that can still be reached can't be collected.

- JavaScript values become eligible for garbage collection when they can't be reached in code.
- The event listener functions of an `events` value are recorded in a map of event listeners of the object: if the object can't be reached in code, the event listeners can't be reached either. *If the only way or reaching them was through the event handler map (they were anonymous) the can be garbage collected*.

Each time `establishSSE` is called it returns a new EventSource object - which, as an object "value", is different than the one returned the previous time it was called.

When passed to `checkStatus`, the value of `events` is held in a closure of the function passed to `setTimeout`. Hence the value will be "reached" when the timeout expires and the timer function executed.

One of two cases occur next

1. The EventSource object in `events` is still open. A new timeout is created by calling `checkStatus` again. This creates a new closure for a new timer callback function, but with the same value of the `events` argument. Hence the (unchanged) value of `events` can still be reached and can't be garbage collected.
2. The event source in `events` has been closed. In this case `checkStatus` calls `establishSSE` (to reopen the source) and returns from the timer call without storing its argument anywhere or retaining it in the scope of a closure that can be executed at a later time. The closed `events` object becomes eligible for garbage collection at this point because it can't be reached.

   `establishSSE` goes on to create a new value held in a variable called `events`, and calls `checkStatus` with it, but it's not the same value as the one going out of scope in the `checkStatus` call above it in the call stack.

However, since `sseReply` and `sseRefresh` are not nested within `estabishSSE`, they won't be garbage collected just because an `event` object value was gc'ed.

---

<sup>1</sup> With an exception: blob or file object arguments passed to [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#usage_notes) are held in memory (while network traffic retrieves their data) and must be explicitly released by calling `URL.revokeObjectURL`.

---

**Answer to Edits**

*Updated after question edit*

> But`events` is no longer accessible from anywhere within the program.

This is an invalid assumption which may have lead to the question:

1. The `events` argument of `checkStatus` is in scope of the timer callback function returned by `checkStatus` because the callback function is nested within `checkStatus`.
2. The callback function is prevented from being garbage collected because the [native code] implementation of `setTimeout` necessarily holds a reference to it.
3. If the value of `events` is not in a closed state, the timer callback creates a new timer callback function by making a fresh call to`checkStatus` using the existing `events` object value, to generate a new callback function for a new `setTimeout` call.
4. Repeat from step 1.

It might be more straight forward and less confusing if `checkStatus` were used as the timer callback directly without making a delayed recursive call to itself, say by passing arguments via `setTimeout`:

```
function checkStatus(events) {
    if (events.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED) { 
          establishSSE(); // create a new EventSource object
          return; // the actual argument object value is now inaccessible
                  // and becomes eligble for garbage collection.
    }
    setTimeout( checkStatus, 500, events);
}
```

If implementing the change above, `establishSS` would also need to pass `checkStatus` to `setTimeout` as its first argument without calling it first:

```
function establishSSE() {
  const events = new EventSource("/sse/" + sseID);

  events.addEventListener("reply", sseReply);
  events.addEventListener("refresh", sseRefresh);

  setTimeout(checkStatus, 500, events);
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how this is the case. I've updated my original question with an EDIT explaining my confusion.

Comment: Are you sure the references to them in the event handler map are garbage collected? Because if that was the case I'm pretty sure the handler functions wouldn't keep running when additional data is received over the network. It doesn't seem like the `events` object going out of scope garbage collects anything.

Comment: The code reopens the eventSource with the same handlers if it gets closed. So if event's keep arriving, the same functions keep getting called - but they're in a new event handler map of a new `events` object value, no?

Comment: I see you updated your answer with the inclusion of only anonymous event handlers being garbage collected, but I fear this is still wrong, or perhaps I am misunderstanding something. I've updated the original post explaining my confusion.

Comment: If the event source is closed, the timer callback creates a new event source listener. If it creates new inline anonymous handlers, they'll get called and do the same thing. They just won't be the same anonymous functions that were called the last time. If you want the handling to stop, don't call `estabishSSE` in the timer callback code!

Comment: I don't feel like this comment really responds to my most recent edit update. I think this entire answer may be wrong because it seems relatively clear that even if the event source object cannot be accessed anywhere in code, it will not be garbage collected, and the event handlers will still occur.

Comment: Of course the handlers won't be called if the EventSource is manually closed. That is the purpose of the close function. I'm saying that `events` going out of scope does not garbage collect any event handlers (even anonymous ones, which contradicts the beginning of your answer)

Comment: You seem to be moving the goal posts a lot. First your answer said that all event handlers will be garbage collected when events goes out of scope. Then you edited it to say only anonymous ones will be garbage collected. And now you're changing your answer again saying only when the event source is manually closed will they be garbage collected, but I think this may _also_ be wrong, as I linked the Chromium source code above and no where in the `close` function does it seem to flag the object for GC, so I fear your entire answer may be misleading.